# Can we use Visual Studio code for both Python and C

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hey I like to use the code for both Python and C.
I am using code for python, and studio for C.

Do we have an option to use code for C too, without ruining the python workspace.

Comment: What do mean by "ruining the workspace"? VS Code works with a variety of languages? What are the changes you're afraid will occur?

Comment: You can open as many Visual Studio Code windows are you'd like and they can all use a separate workspace. There is no reason to be worried that opening your C project and Python project at the same time would cause any problems.

Answer (score -1):

visual studio is an all in one IDE for any environment you want to code in. On installation you get to select the IDE's you will use and all of these run in separate work space. No worries anymore about running python and c on separate IDE's. You can do both in one space.

Comment: Thanks for that let me try